# C++ how can i remove vector of pointers in my game

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, sfml

Im trying to make first game sth simillar to Tanks. But my game crashes when i try to delete the enemy tank (sometimes works, sometimes not) and i have no any idea what is wrong with my code. Will you help me?

```
void Game::update(sf::Time elapsedTime){

if (enemies.size() < 6){

    eTank1 = new EnemyTank(150, 130);
    enemies.push_back(eTank1);
    }

    tank->move(elapsedTime);

for (vector<EnemyTank*>::const_iterator it = enemies.begin(); it != enemies.end();)
{

    if (collision->checkCollisionWithEnemyTankAndTank(tank, *it)){
        (*it)->move(elapsedTime);
    }


    collision->checkShoot(tank->getBulletsVector(), tank, *it); 

    //probably there is a problem
    if ((*it)->getlife() <= 0){

        delete  *it;            
        enemies.erase(it);
        cout << "TANGO DOWN" << endl;
    }
     ++it;
}
```

checkShoot looks like this:

```
void Collision::checkShoot(vector <Bullet*> &bullet, Tank *tank, EnemyTank* enemyTank){

distance = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < bullet.size(); i++){


    distance = abs(bullet[i]->getPosition().x - enemyTank->getPosition().x) + abs(bullet[i]->getPosition().y - enemyTank->getPosition().y);

    if (distance < 45){
        cout << "act life: " << enemyTank->getlife() << endl;
        enemyTank->setLife();       // -0.5 from actual life        
        tank->setVector(i);         // delete bullet from vector        

    }

}
```

}

And the code of destructor

```
cout << "DESTRU";
delete tank_bullet;

for (auto &it : bullets){ delete it; } bullets.clear();


cout << "DESTRU T - END\n";
```

Finally the setVector(i);

```
void setVector(int index){
     if (!bullets.empty()){
        delete (bullets.at(index));
        bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + index);
    }
```

}

Comment: You can not blindly [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) from a vector you're iterating over, as the [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) will invalidate iterators. However, you might be interested in what the [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) function returns.

Comment: Google "erase-remove idiom".

Comment: Can you give me more information about solution for my problem? i don't exactly know how to resolve this crashes. Thanks.

Comment: @user3419495 as Joachim pointed out, you should assign the return value from erase to the iterator `it = enemies.erase(it);` instead of `++it`

Comment: There is a chance that you missed that tiny little information @alarge pointed out in his answer to put the `++it` into an else branch :). You should also think about your container, since removing from a vector is especially a complex operation if the element is not at the end of the vector itself. However if you do not remove that frequently it might still be a good choice. Also you can swap the element you're going to remove with the back of the vector and just call the `pop_back()` function if the order of your elements do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really is in the comments, but in case they feel too terse, I'm writing a slightly longer explanation.

Here's a minimal example similar in style to your code:

```
int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  for(auto it = v.cbegin(); it != v.cend(); ) {
    if(*it == 5)
      v.erase(it);
    ++it;
  }
}
```

This segfaults (doesn't if you compare to something that is not the last element of the `vector`, e.g. `*it == 3`, but this behaviour is probably compiler-dependent). Why? `v.erase(it)` invalidates the iterator `it`, so you can't be using `it` after that line. Instead, you should be using what `erase` returns, `it = v.erase(it)`, which is the iterator following the deleted one. Now if that happens to be `v.cend()` and on the next line you increment it, `++it`, you're out of bounds and out of luck.

I am not encouraging you to use the following, but if you want to keep with the style of your code, what should work is

```
if(*it == 5)
  it = v.erase(it);
else
  ++it;
```

What the `else` does is it avoids the double incrementation on `erase`.